# Giving Windows user permissions in Samba shares

Tags: server, permissions, windows, samba, users

I'm pretty new to Linux and especially to Samba.

so, I installed samba and created a share.
my Windows server and client PC's can connect to it.
but I want to give the different Windows users different permissions in the sub folders. but I don't know what I need to do?

btw in global settings the workgroup = WORKGROUP , and security = user ,the Windows users and server can still connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know complicated the permissions per user you require but does something like this work for you : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2453008

In that situation the user created a share of one folder ( /FolderRoot ) with many subfolders with the intent that only some users would have access to each subfolder.

He wanted the parent folder and the whole tree to be read/writeable to only one user ( User1 ) for which I suggested this:

```
[FolderRoot]
path = /FolderRoot
read only = no
valid users = User1
force user = UserMaster
```

Then he wanted a subfoler that only User1 and User3 could access. I suggested just creating a different share of that subfolder like this:

```
[Folder2]
path = /FolderRoot/Folder2
read only = no
valid users = User1, User3
force user = UserMaster
```

You might want to look at the original posters question to see how applicable his use case is to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question? https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/samba-file-server

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: i have seen many answers on this site the same format as mine and no one has complained about them guess i am special

Comment: no it doesnt unfortunately, i have 5 windows users, and the samba share has multiple folders, not all users are allowed in all folders. i need to set separate permissions for them. but i dont know exactly how to

Comment: @David I'm not sure which answer you saw but link only answers are generally discouraged since your answer might become irrelevant if the link is removed or the content on the link changes. Please see the post which I have linked in my previous comment.